# How to override onclose event on WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to override the onclose event on WPF, this is my code so far:

```
protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
       base.OnClosing(e);
       e.Cancel = true;
       //do my stuff before closing
}
```

It executes the code but the application never closes. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The application never closes because you are setting `e.Cancel` to `true`.

Try

```
protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
       //do my stuff before closing

       base.OnClosing(e);       
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You are asking it not to close by setting `e.Cancel = true`.  Just don't do that.