# How to delete file, then user closes program in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I know full path of file  `var temp_file = Path.Combine(_directoryName1, "temp.ini");` which need to be deleted in the end of program working. How could I do this ? As I know it is possible to realize via OncloseEvent().  In addition, I dont know exatly how user will close application via `alt+f4` or via buttons.

So far, I have tried to use this code below from almost the same question [How to override onclose event on WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774849/how-to-override-onclose-event-on-wpf)

```
protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
       //do my stuff before closing

       base.OnClosing(e);        
}
```

And I have added it in App.xaml.cs but it doesn't work. VS2013 says that he don't know such method `base.OnClosing(e);`

Is there any mistake or another way out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Window.Closing` is for a specific `Window`. That's probably not what you want in any case, because the `Closing` event can be cancelled. `Window.Closed` is likely a better choice.

To run something when the program is closed -- not tying yourself to a window -- you should subscribe to the [`Application.Exit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.exit.aspx) event instead.

Comment: [OnExit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.onexit(v=vs.110).aspx) is also available to override.