# WPF : How to override Loaded Event in a Custom Control

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, events, custom-controls

I would like to override the `Loaded` event in my Custom control but I don't know how to do it.

I wanted to do like this example but knowing that `base.OnLoaded` does not exist I don't know how to do it

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28326029/14338640

> You can create a custom control and override the events. refer the
> below code i tried for TextBox control.
>
> ```
> class TextBoxEx : TextBox {
>     protected override void OnTouchUp(System.Windows.Input.TouchEventArgs e)
>     {
>         base.OnTouchUp(e);
>     }
>
>     protected override void OnTouchDown(System.Windows.Input.TouchEventArgs e)
>     {
>        base.OnTouchDown(e);
>     } 
> }
> ```

For information my custom control inherits from `UserControl`.

Comment: Attach a Loaded event handler in the control's constructor.

Comment: @Clemens `Handles MyBase.Loaded` ? Let's say it works. How do I call `MyBase.OnLoad` since this function doesn't exist ?

Comment: No need to call any base class method. The base class method calls your event handler. Take a look at the online documentation of the Loaded event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not "override an event". You override a method or attach an event handler.

Since there is no `OnLoaded` method to override, your only option is to attach an event handler.

```
public YourControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += OnLoaded;
}

private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: It is necessary, otherwise your UserControl would not load its XAML. Note that you could alternatively also attach the handler in XAML by `<UserControl ... Loaded="OnLoaded">`.